# How do you open up a different save file in Pokemon Moon without deleting the other one?

Tags: pokemon-sun-moon

I just found out that I had my sister's save file (we both share the Pokemon Moon cartridge) and I am wondering how to open another save file without deleting her's?

Answer (score 9):

You cannot start a new save file without deleting the old one. Pokemon games never supported multiple save slots and Sun and Moon are no different. You would have to delete the old save file to start a new game.

Comment: Buying another cartridge you "solve" the problem. Being there why not buy a copy of Sun...

Comment: That is a very valid answer while it does solve the problem of multiple saves I was just answering the whole can you open a second save slot. I may add that to my answer if you are fine with that.

Comment: placed it here because I thought it was a good complement ;)

Answer (score 1):

If you go through the process of installing CFW (custom firmware) onto your 3DS, it's possible to have two different save files via the use of a save manager. I am aware that this question is really old, but in case anyone else wants to do it, I'll leave this link here: [3ds.guide](http://3ds.guide)

Answer (score 1):

You can't have two save files. I recommend you just buy Pokemon Sun, because if you have another 3ds, you can trade pokemon to and from pokemon sun and have the chance to complete the entire Alolan Pokedex, considering the fact that each game has different pokemon.

Answer (score -1):

If you have a second SDHC card, then you can play on one card, and your sister can play on another card.

Comment: Save data is saved on the cartridge, not to your SD card.

Comment: except if you have downloaded it via the Nintendo eShop

Answer (score -2):

(Copied my answer from a similar question. The same applies)

(I read that someone asked if this was legal. Yes, it is. As you are just modifying the hardware you bought. However, using PIRATED Games using Homebrew, is Illegal. Don't use Pirated games!)

Yes. This is possible, However for this you will need to install Homebrew. Homebrew is a Custom Firmware that allows stuff such as:

Custom Themes,
Roms,
Save Managing and Manipulating (Export a save, Create Pokemon on your PC using PKHeX, Then Import the save) (Or just export the save and it will be there)
Etc.

I recently reset my Omega Ruby since I didn't know what to do in Sun, so I felt like replaying Omega Ruby. But Since I had a lot of Pokemon on there, I made a backup using JK's Save Manager. If you would like to install Homebrew, don't recklessly mess around in your 3DS's files, but instead use a video tutorial.

Here's some links I found to help with the Homebrew installation:

https://wiki.gbatemp.net/wiki/List_of_3DS_homebrew (List of Homebrew Apps that work with Homebrew)

(How to use PKHeX and Save Manager with Sun and Moon. This is probably what you want. You can export the save and just leave it at that.)

(How to install Homebrew on Any 3DS)

(I recommend you also save the files on your computer - in case something goes wrong (Rare chance), you won't lose your saves!)

If you don't want to Install Homebrew, then either buy a new cartridge, or delete the existing save.

Comment: While it's legal, it's a violation of the Terms of Service. If you're found out, you will be banned from any and all online activities.

Comment: It is? Isn't it only when you cheat in games etc? I added the part that you could gen Pokemon just as an additional feature. I don't personally do it, but Is modding the 3DS In general against the T.O.S.?

Comment: @GlitchyShadowZ I'm fairly sure it is. Nintendo is extremely protective of their products, and installing homebrew can brick your device (potentially, if done incorrectly).

Comment: There's a reason Homebrew stops working after most of the 3DS updates. Generally, if a company actively fights something, you can be pretty certain they also have a clause in their ToS against it.